# Semaphore symbols not found (c)

Tags: c, semaphore, symbols

So I have made a method using semaphores.

My program opens with

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
```

And my make file is

```
officeHours: officeHours.c
    gcc -o officeHours officeHours.c -lpthread -lrt
```

**EDIT: added -lrt....no change**

However when I make the file it finds can't find the symbols for

sem_destroy
sem_getvalue
sem_init
sem_post
sem_wait

why is this?

**Edit: output from "make officeHours"**

```
cc -o officeHours officeHours.c
"officeHours.c", line 4: warning: invalid white space character in directive
"officeHours.c", line 5: warning: invalid white space character in directive
"officeHours.c", line 41: warning: argument #3 is incompatible with prototype:
    prototype: pointer to function(pointer to void) returning pointer to void : "/usr/include/pthread.h", line 197
    argument: pointer to void
"officeHours.c", line 68: warning: argument #3 is incompatible with prototype:
    prototype: pointer to function(pointer to void) returning pointer to void : "/usr/include/pthread.h", line 197
    argument: pointer to void
Undefined symbol            first referenced in file
sem_destroy                 officeHours.o
sem_getvalue                officeHours.o
sem_init                    officeHours.o
sem_post                    officeHours.o
sem_wait                    officeHours.o
```

Comment: if you look at the first line of your Makefile output, you'll see that  it's invoking a different command: `cc -o officeHours officeHours.c`

Comment: hmm.....why would it be doing that? my make file is exactly as seen above

Comment: also, if that was the case, wouldn't the compiler also complain about pthread_create and pthread_join because they come from -lpthread

Answer (score 1):

You need to link with the `librt` library.

This library contains POSIX realtime extensions.

```
officeHours: officeHours.c
    gcc -o officeHours officeHours.c -lpthread -lrt
```

If you look at the man page for `sem_init(3RT)`:

```
cc [ flag... ] file... -lrt [ library... ]
#include <semaphore.h>

int sem_init(sem_t *sem, int pshared, unsigned int value);
```

Comment: while the line gcc -o officeHours officeHours.c -lpthread -lrt seems to work in command line.....the make file seems to still have no change

Comment: the makefile is in the original comment.
I just edited with the added -lrt

Comment: Can you post the entire gcc/Make output?

Comment: k I added it for you there